# Ruby How to send image over tcp (http) server to client

Tags: ruby, image, http, tcp, content-type

I am trying to create a simple http server but when i send an png file firefox tells me that there are problems with the image. (the image can not be display).

I changed the content type to octed-stream so i can download the file from the browser. 
By comparing the original image and the downloaded image with the text editor I realized that the     downloaded one missed some lines in the beginning.

```
# Provides TCPServer and TCPSocket classes
require 'socket' 

server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 1234)
ary = Array.new
f = File.binread '/Users/serrulez/Documents/GIT/KOS_Simple_HTTP_Server/Shrek.png'

loop do
  socket = server.accept
  request = socket.gets

  index1 = request.index(' ');
  index2 = request.index(' ',index1+1);
  index3 = request.index("\r\n");
  index4 = request.length;

  method = request[0,index1]
  URI = request[index1+1,index2-index1-1]
  version = request[index2+1,index3-index2-1]
  CRLF = b2s((request[index3,2] == "\r\n"))

  if (URI == "/Shrek" || URI == "/index.html")
    socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: image/png\r\n" +
    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"

    ary = Array.new

    f = File.binread '/Users/serrulez/Documents/GIT/KOS_Simple_HTTP_Server/Shrek.png'
    #if I print 'f' here to the console i get the hole image, but downloaded from the browser
    #the upper part ist cut
    puts f
    ary.push(f)

    socket.write(ary) # <- update, forgot to copy this line
  end
  socket.close
end
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it - where is the write to the socket?

Comment: HTTP headers terminate with an empty line. Try adding a second `\r\n` after `"Content-Type: image/png\r\n"`

Comment: You're right I added a \r\n. The socket.write was also added, I forgot to copy that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. The last piece to add was the encoding (see below)

```
 if (URI == "/Shrek")
 socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                 "Content-Type: image/png; charset=utf-8\r\n" +
                 "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I now get the whole image with the above code but my characters are escaped.

The original image starts with :

```
�PNG
IHDR�H
�_jsRGB���gAMA���a
[...]
```

and the image I receive with the browser starts with;

```
["\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xF3\x00\x00\x01H\b\x02\x00\x00\x00\n\xEE_j\x0
```